# Django manage.py dumpdata command only dumping 2000 rows only per table

Tags: python, mysql, django

we are migrating the data of our django application to a new environment. Normally we would just be using the built in `dumpdata` management command to create a dump of all our tables and then load everything back into the new environment using `loaddata`.

To be precise, we are using the following command to create the db dump without the `auth.permissions` and `contenttypes` tables:

`python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --natural-primary -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --indent 2 > db.json`

We noticed, that the result only contains a maximum of 2000 rows per table. As some of our tables have got 8000-15.000 records, we are missing data, when importing the dump in the new environment.

**What we did / tried so far**

- we tried different combinations of arguments for the dumpdata command
- we tried other formats like jsonl or xml
- we did not change anything in the serializers
- we found out that it might be a limitation to the db running out of memory
- we found out that we might need to adapt the max_allowed_packets for our db (64mb at the moment)

**Used Django Version and packages**

- Django==3.2.15
- mysql-connector-python==8.0.30
- pyyaml==6.0
- *others*

**Questions**

- does anybody have a clue what we are not seeing here?
- if it is due to the mysql max_allowed_packets setting - how can we change it? We are running our db and application in a docker container

If further information is needed we are happy to share it.

Answer (score 0):

We actually solved this problem by copying the original `dumpdata.py` from the Django installation and making a few changes to it:

```
185c185
<                     queryset = objects.using(using).order_by(model._meta.pk.name)
---
>                     queryset = objects.using(using).all()
191c191,192
<                         yield from queryset.iterator()
---
>                         for row in queryset:
>                             yield row
```

This is the whole new file, `<app>/management/commands/dumpdata2.py`:

```
import gzip
import os
import warnings

from django.apps import apps
from django.core import serializers
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.core.management.utils import parse_apps_and_model_labels
from django.db import DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, router

try:
    import bz2
    has_bz2 = True
except ImportError:
    has_bz2 = False

try:
    import lzma
    has_lzma = True
except ImportError:
    has_lzma = False


class ProxyModelWarning(Warning):
    pass


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = (
        "Output the contents of the database as a fixture of the given format "
        "(using each model's default manager unless --all is specified)."
    )

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            'args', metavar='app_label[.ModelName]', nargs='*',
            help='Restricts dumped data to the specified app_label or app_label.ModelName.',
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '--format', default='json',
            help='Specifies the output serialization format for fixtures.',
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '--indent', type=int,
            help='Specifies the indent level to use when pretty-printing output.',
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '--database',
            default=DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS,
            help='Nominates a specific database to dump fixtures from. '
                 'Defaults to the "default" database.',
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-e', '--exclude', action='append', default=[],
            help='An app_label or app_label.ModelName to exclude '
                 '(use multiple --exclude to exclude multiple apps/models).',
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '--natural-foreign', action='store_true', dest='use_natural_foreign_keys',
            help='Use natural foreign keys if they are available.',
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '--natural-primary', action='store_true', dest='use_natural_primary_keys',
            help='Use natural primary keys if they are available.',
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-a', '--all', action='store_true', dest='use_base_manager',
            help="Use Django's base manager to dump all models stored in the database, "
                 "including those that would otherwise be filtered or modified by a custom manager.",
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '--pks', dest='primary_keys',
            help="Only dump objects with given primary keys. Accepts a comma-separated "
                 "list of keys. This option only works when you specify one model.",
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            '-o', '--output',
            help='Specifies file to which the output is written.'
        )

    def handle(self, *app_labels, **options):
        format = options['format']
        indent = options['indent']
        using = options['database']
        excludes = options['exclude']
        output = options['output']
        show_traceback = options['traceback']
        use_natural_foreign_keys = options['use_natural_foreign_keys']
        use_natural_primary_keys = options['use_natural_primary_keys']
        use_base_manager = options['use_base_manager']
        pks = options['primary_keys']

        if pks:
            primary_keys = [pk.strip() for pk in pks.split(',')]
        else:
            primary_keys = []

        excluded_models, excluded_apps = parse_apps_and_model_labels(excludes)

        if not app_labels:
            if primary_keys:
                raise CommandError("You can only use --pks option with one model")
            app_list = dict.fromkeys(
                app_config for app_config in apps.get_app_configs()
                if app_config.models_module is not None and app_config not in excluded_apps
            )
        else:
            if len(app_labels) > 1 and primary_keys:
                raise CommandError("You can only use --pks option with one model")
            app_list = {}
            for label in app_labels:
                try:
                    app_label, model_label = label.split('.')
                    try:
                        app_config = apps.get_app_config(app_label)
                    except LookupError as e:
                        raise CommandError(str(e))
                    if app_config.models_module is None or app_config in excluded_apps:
                        continue
                    try:
                        model = app_config.get_model(model_label)
                    except LookupError:
                        raise CommandError("Unknown model: %s.%s" % (app_label, model_label))

                    app_list_value = app_list.setdefault(app_config, [])

                    # We may have previously seen an "all-models" request for
                    # this app (no model qualifier was given). In this case
                    # there is no need adding specific models to the list.
                    if app_list_value is not None and model not in app_list_value:
                        app_list_value.append(model)
                except ValueError:
                    if primary_keys:
                        raise CommandError("You can only use --pks option with one model")
                    # This is just an app - no model qualifier
                    app_label = label
                    try:
                        app_config = apps.get_app_config(app_label)
                    except LookupError as e:
                        raise CommandError(str(e))
                    if app_config.models_module is None or app_config in excluded_apps:
                        continue
                    app_list[app_config] = None

        # Check that the serialization format exists; this is a shortcut to
        # avoid collating all the objects and _then_ failing.
        if format not in serializers.get_public_serializer_formats():
            try:
                serializers.get_serializer(format)
            except serializers.SerializerDoesNotExist:
                pass

            raise CommandError("Unknown serialization format: %s" % format)

        def get_objects(count_only=False):
            """
            Collate the objects to be serialized. If count_only is True, just
            count the number of objects to be serialized.
            """
            if use_natural_foreign_keys:
                models = serializers.sort_dependencies(app_list.items(), allow_cycles=True)
            else:
                # There is no need to sort dependencies when natural foreign
                # keys are not used.
                models = []
                for (app_config, model_list) in app_list.items():
                    if model_list is None:
                        models.extend(app_config.get_models())
                    else:
                        models.extend(model_list)
            for model in models:
                if model in excluded_models:
                    continue
                if model._meta.proxy and model._meta.proxy_for_model not in models:
                    warnings.warn(
                        "%s is a proxy model and won't be serialized." % model._meta.label,
                        category=ProxyModelWarning,
                    )
                if not model._meta.proxy and router.allow_migrate_model(using, model):
                    if use_base_manager:
                        objects = model._base_manager
                    else:
                        objects = model._default_manager

                    queryset = objects.using(using).all()
                    if primary_keys:
                        queryset = queryset.filter(pk__in=primary_keys)
                    if count_only:
                        yield queryset.order_by().count()
                    else:
                        for row in queryset:
                            yield row

        try:
            self.stdout.ending = None
            progress_output = None
            object_count = 0
            # If dumpdata is outputting to stdout, there is no way to display progress
            if output and self.stdout.isatty() and options['verbosity'] > 0:
                progress_output = self.stdout
                object_count = sum(get_objects(count_only=True))
            if output:
                file_root, file_ext = os.path.splitext(output)
                compression_formats = {
                    '.bz2': (open, {}, file_root),
                    '.gz': (gzip.open, {}, output),
                    '.lzma': (open, {}, file_root),
                    '.xz': (open, {}, file_root),
                    '.zip': (open, {}, file_root),
                }
                if has_bz2:
                    compression_formats['.bz2'] = (bz2.open, {}, output)
                if has_lzma:
                    compression_formats['.lzma'] = (
                        lzma.open, {'format': lzma.FORMAT_ALONE}, output
                    )
                    compression_formats['.xz'] = (lzma.open, {}, output)
                try:
                    open_method, kwargs, file_path = compression_formats[file_ext]
                except KeyError:
                    open_method, kwargs, file_path = (open, {}, output)
                if file_path != output:
                    file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
                    warnings.warn(
                        f"Unsupported file extension ({file_ext}). "
                        f"Fixtures saved in '{file_name}'.",
                        RuntimeWarning,
                    )
                stream = open_method(file_path, 'wt', **kwargs)
            else:
                stream = None
            try:
                serializers.serialize(
                    format, get_objects(), indent=indent,
                    use_natural_foreign_keys=use_natural_foreign_keys,
                    use_natural_primary_keys=use_natural_primary_keys,
                    stream=stream or self.stdout, progress_output=progress_output,
                    object_count=object_count,
                )
            finally:
                if stream:
                    stream.close()
        except Exception as e:
            if show_traceback:
                raise
            raise CommandError("Unable to serialize database: %s" % e)
```